Token Создание токена на блокчейне Солана
подскажите ресурс для создания 100% токена на блокчейне Солана. Пишет следующее в разделе создать токен: баланс SOL кошелька низкий подписание транзакции может не состояться. Какое количество SOL необходимо для продолжения создания токена и будет ли токен доступен на биржах ?
